# How to get the sum of each branch in hierarchical data structure with sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

**I have the next Tree Structure :**

[image]

This structure is represented in the database with the next Table:

```
--------------------------------Employees-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        Employee_name         |           Global_Team             |       Team      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_of_head_of_engineering   |           -                       | Engineering     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_1_T1                     |         Engineering               | Team_1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_2_T1                     |         Engineering               | Team_1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_3_T1                     |         Engineering               | Team_1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_4_T1                     |         Engineering               | Team_1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_5_T1                     |         Engineering               | Team_1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_2_T2                     |         Engineering               | Team_2          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_1_T2_1                   |         Team_2                    | 2_Team_1        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_2_T2_1                   |         Team_2                    | 2_Team_1        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name_1_T2_2                   |         Team_2                    | 2_Team_2        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|name_2_T2_2                   |         Team_2                    | 2_Team_2        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|name_3_T2_2                   |         Team_2                    | 2_Team_2        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need the number of employee per each team, **result should looks like that**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|        Team                |           count_employee             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Engineering                |               11                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Team_1                     |               5                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Team_2                     |               6                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2_Team_1                   |               2                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 2_Team_2                   |               3                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have Tried with:

```
Select  Team, count(employee_name),  from Employees Group by Team
```

I got those results :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|        Team                |           count_employee             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Engineering                |               1                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Team_1                     |               5                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Team_2                     |               1                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2_Team_1                   |               2                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 2_Team_2                   |               3                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

to be more specific if we start from the top "Engineering" we should get the number of all employees under it or under teams inside it, as well for teams and sub-teams.

Comment: no it isn't represented in that table you need a tree for that

Comment: no tree, we have the table, and we need to achieve the tree shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that your table structure is not designed to implement a hierarchy tree. For example, if you delete `name_2_T2, Engineering, Team_2`, then `Team_2` with all its employees will be lost for the `Engeneering` team.

But if you want to count the employees in each team with this sample data, here is the query you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.team,
    (
        WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
            SELECT 
                ee.team,
                ee.global_team
            FROM employees ee
            WHERE ee.team = e.team
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                ee.team,
                ee.global_team
            FROM employees ee
            JOIN cte ON ee.global_team = cte.team
        )
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE global_team IS NOT NULL
    ) AS count_employee
FROM employees e
ORDER BY count_employee DESC
```

Output

| team | count_employee |
| --- | --- |
| Engineering | 11 |
| Team_2 | 6 |
| Team_1 | 5 |
| 2_Team_2 | 3 |
| 2_Team_1 | 2 |

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c54f276e76d95ebba5e86ff38d77cfb2)